# Full control, Limited Access given through a group where the user does not exist?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, inheritance, sharepoint-permissions

I have a SharePoint site where, when searching for a user at site level (using check permissions) it comes back saying the user has "Full control, limited access - Given through the 'Site Name' Owners Group.

However, the user is not an Owner of the site and when I click into the Owners group, they are not listed in there either.

How is this user being provided with access at site level from the specified group when they don't appear to be in that group and how would I go about visualising and removing these user permissions?

I should add that when I click the "There are limited access users on this site. Users may have limited access if an item or document under the site has been shared with them. Show users". It doesn't show any additional users, but instead replaces 'Full Control' with 'Full Control, Limited Access' against the Site Owners group.

Comment: Is it sub site? Permission inheritance broken on this site?

Comment: It's not a sub site.

Answer (score 0):

Check below things:

1. If user is a part of Site collection administrators
2. If user has been granted permissions via Microsoft 365 group

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that user is not part of Site collection administrators and also the user has not been granted permissions via any 365 group.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem before. You could use PowerShell to remove the user.

```
#Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emily"
$UserID="emily@tenant.com"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Site
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential $cred
 
#sharepoint online powershell remove user permissions from site collection
Remove-SPOUser -Site $SiteURL -LoginName $UserID
```